# What's the sudden pitching of Rocket Lab's 'It's Business Time" launch at separation?

Tags: attitude, rocketlab, electron, stage-separation

In today's Rocket Lab launch of the "It's Business Time" mission, there was a substantial and swift change in attitude upon stage separation.

It looks scary. I understand that

- The first stage of a two-stage rocket could be said to be about **going up high enough** as quickly as possible, while
- The second stage could be said to be about **going sideways fast enough** as quickly as possible, but this looks like a sudden right-angle turn!

**Question:** Is such a sudden turn planned, or was there some bug with stage separation? If planned, why so <s>serious</s> sudden?

The reason I made the GIF is to help highlight the nozzle's vectoring activity.

Below GIF is hacked from screen shots from the Rocket Lab YouTube video [It's Business Time Launch - 11/11/2018](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPwMuUxSrcA) Sorry for the low quality, I don't know a good and easy to use tool to make GIFs from long YouTube videos.

It's showing 2x normal speed. Once you get the idea here, go to the same play time in the video and you can watch at any speed YouTube allows.

[image]

Comment: a few things I noticed: (1) 1st stage accelerates almost straight up, so a correction to a tangential trajectory is needed. (2) In the 15 seconds before separation, the stack tilts in the opposite direction - this needs to be corrected.  (3) I don't see any attempt to correct attitude after the fast swing. My impression in summary: The strong swing was planned, the slight swing before and after separation might not.

Comment: @asdfex I've slightly modified the statement of the question in the text, adding *If planned, why so sudden?* I didn't realize it wasn't there until seeing your comment, thanks!

Comment: I'm just guessing, but maybe they didn't want to turn the full stack to reduce load on the first stage. And after separation there is no reason to stay upright any longer. It really looks like separation took place in a much more upright position compared to e.g. Falcon

Comment: @asdfex there is a camera switch during the GIF; at first south is "up" (about 1:30 on a clock) we can see land north of the launch site, and it looks to me that that's what it would look like if the rocket had started pitching slightly south. After the bright light South is now "down" at 7:00 and we can see even farther north, consistent with more pitching southward. Am I seeing it wrong?

Comment: Indeed, so first a slow turn, then some tumbling between MECO and starting the second stage, then a quick turn in the same direction.

Comment: Seems to swing in one direction by design then corrected pilot or program because it may have or could be be calculated as a 1 time maneuver to change direction during separation?